# Verifying console output using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

My script

> start /wait /b groovy -cp %webservicejarpath% importFile.groovy -p ProcessYYY -i PDF"

gives the following console output somewhat like this::

> Successfully executed the pdf 'data.PDF ' in process unit 'ProcessYYY '.
>   Return value:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <finalresult process="ProcessYYY" >
    <info result="successful"   time="12:11:12" totalfilesimported="1" errorimportedfiles="0">
    <jobs class="PDFIMPORT">
        <job id="Job1003"/>
    </jobs>
   </info>
  </finalresult>
```

The problem is I don't know how to capture this information and verify the result using batch script.
For eg. : if (result=="successful") && (errorimportedfiles==0) Then Echo "Import of PDF is successfull".

Is there a way to verify the result using batch scritping?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put the console output to a file and scan the file with batch: `start /wait /b groovy -cp %webservicejarpath% importFile.groovy -p ProcessYYY -i PDF" >ERROR.LOG`. Try first to make the log file.

Comment: @Endoro: Thanks for suggesting a solution. I will try to create a log and then parse the log file with the values.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok..I just logged in now to check for the answers. And i saw ur comment. BTW, I always do my handful to accept an answer whenever I find that it solves my problem even a bit. Anyway, thx for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find to look for text in the output.

```
start /wait /b groovy -cp %webservicejarpath% importFile.groovy -p ProcessYYY -i PDF" > out.txt

type out.txt | find "successful"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto success

goto fail


:success
REM SUCCESS, Do what work you want due to a success
echo "The import is successful"
goto end


:fail
REM Fail, DO what work you want because it failed.
echo "The import was not successful"



:end
```

You can put anything in the place of **"Successfully executed the pdf"** string that is unique to a successful result.

the variable %ERRORLEVEL% is set for the last command run, the last command being FIND, so if it finds the string "Successfully executed the pdf" then the %ERRORLEVEL% will be 0

It will be equal 1 if there is an error.

Change the code, outputs to a file instead, normally piping the find command on the end will work, but if it's not for this command then saving to a file first then checking the file might, Endoro mentions this way in his comments too.

Martyn

Comment: Hi Martyn, thanks for the solution.It will solve my issue pretty well. I will try to incorporate your idea. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: So here it goes, start /wait /b groovy -cp %webservicejarpath% importFile.groovy -p ProcessYYY -i PDF" | Find "info result="..and rest as u said..The problem is that the cursor waits as it finds  the text and thus the script below is not executed. So Nothing is echoed. In this way also, the full result is also not displayed to console but only the part is displayed till where it finds the text...Any further suggestion?

Comment: edited the answer to include a goto fail after the error check, my mistake. would you mind posting what you have in your batch file?

Comment: start /wait /b groovy -cp %webservicejarpath% importFile.groovy -p ProcessYYY -i PDF" | Find "info result="

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto success
goto fail
:success
REM SUCCESS, Do what work you want due to a success
Echo "The import is successful"
goto end

:fail
REM Fail, DO what work you want because it failed.
Echo "The import is not successful"
:end

Comment: I dont know how to format the code while commenting here. Hope u gets it. anyway now the output is only a single line, which contains the text "info result=" and the cursor just waits there. The output hence is  <info result="successful"   time="12:11:12" totalfilesimported="1" errorimportedfiles="0">..I dont want the console output to change, just that if it finds the text, it echoes the message.

Comment: Edited answer, sounds like piping a command after this doesnt seem to work. it works for everything i've had to do in the past, but Ive never used groovy so maybe it doesn't like it.